# jquery.getJSON() call back function doesn't execute

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, getjson

I have write some code to perform deletion operation by ajax call. The C# code is given below.

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public JsonResult Delete(Guid code)
        {
            Genre obj = null;
            //TODO : FIX HACK
            try
            {
                obj = Genre.Fetch(code, CurrentUserId, null);

                if (obj != null)
                    obj.Delete(CurrentUserId, null);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new
                {
                    deleted = false
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            return Json(new
            {
                deleted = true
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Then I have used jquery getJSON() as follows:

```
function deleteGenre(code) {

    $.getJSON("/Administration/Genre/Delete?code=" + code,
        function (data) {
            if (!data.deleted) {
                alert("WARNING - You cannot delete a genre that is currently in use.");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                //window.location('/Administration/Genre/Edit');
                return false;
            }

        });

}
```

But when I execute the jquery script, the callback function doesn't execute. Though when I visit the link (../Administration/Genre/Delete?code=835e56f0-a339-4da9-8cbb-d93b12a01d37) through browser valid result ({"deleted":false}) comes.

How can I solve this issue. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/Administration/Genre/Delete` and `../Administration/Genre/Delete` may not resolve to the same location.

Comment: How do you call `deleteGenre` method? Can you add the code for this?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is the solution but you are supposed to use Single Quote and not the double quotes when calling the method through this function like the following:

```
$.getJSON('/Administration/Genre/Delete?code='
```

Comment: There is no difference in this case.